# SwiftUI Label for Button won't show text when the text is a class variable changed by a class function

Tags: class, user-interface, button, swiftui, class-variables

I have a class that has a text variable and a function that changes the text variable based on an integer variable thats also in the class. The text variable is used as the label for a button. When I do something to change the int variable I expect the text shown to change as well but it doesn’t.  When I tried printing the text variable to see if it was changing along with the int it was but for some reason the text of the button just won't change.

```
import SwiftUI

class thing{
    var str: String
    var int: Int
    
    func change(){
        self.str = "\(int*5)"
    }
    
    init(str: String, int: Int) {
        self.str = str
        self.int = int
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var cla: thing
    
    init(cla: thing = thing(str:"Hello World", int: 5)) {
        self.cla = cla
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(){
            cla.change()
            print(cla.str)
        }label: {
            Text(cla.str)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This has been really puzzling me for a while and I'd really appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: `@State` will only automatically notify the `View` when a property on a _value type_ changes. SwiftUI isn't built to watch a `class` like this -- this is a fundamental characteristic of the framework. If you _need_ to use a class for some reason, use an `ObservedObject`

Comment: You could just change to `struct thing` and `mutating func change()`
 and you are good to go. @jnpdx advice stands, a class is a reference type, a struct is a value type, which the View can look after using the `@State`. Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app: 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).